YOLOv7 Training: Local File Path Error in Google Colab
I'm trying to train a YOLOv7 model on Google Colab, but I keep encountering an issue where the model is trying to use a local file path, resulting in an error. Here's the error message I'm seeing:
AssertionError: Image Not Found C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dataset\images\train\person10_000001.jpg

I cloned the YOLOv7 repository from GitHub into Google Colab and attempted to run the training script with the following command:
%cd /content/drive/MyDrive/YOLO/YOLO/yolov7
!python /content/drive/MyDrive/YOLO/YOLO/yolov7/train.py --batch 16 --cfg /content/drive/MyDrive/YOLO/YOLO/yolov7/cfg/training/yolov7.yaml --epochs 50 --data /content/drive/MyDrive/YOLO/YOLO/yolov7/data.yaml --weights '/content/drive/MyDrive/YOLO/YOLO/yolov7/yolov7.pt' --device 0

data.yaml
train: /content/drive/MyDrive/YOLO/YOLO/dataset/images/train
val: /content/drive/MyDrive/YOLO/YOLO/dataset/images/val

nc: 1
names: ['person']


How can I resolve this issue and ensure the model uses the correct Google Drive paths when training in Colab after cloning the YOLOv7 repository?
